# CAST jsonb column into INT[]

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm in a situation where I get a jsonb value (from the `scrape` field which is jsonb) that looks like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(scrape->'amenity_ids', '[]'::jsonb) AS ids
FROM my_table

ids                                                                                                          |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[]                                                                                                           |
[33, 34, 35, 4, 5, 37, 8, 40, 9, 41, 42, 11, 44, 45, 46, 47, 16, 21, 56]                                     |
[129, 35, 4, 36, 37, 103, 40, 41, 45, 77, 17, 23, 30]                                                        |
[1, 33, 34, 35, 4, 36, 8, 40, 41, 44, 45, 77, 46, 47, 85, 56, 90, 91, 92, 93, 30, 95]                        |
[1, 129, 2, 4, 8, 9, 77, 85, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 30, 94, 95, 96, 33, 34, 100, 37, 38, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 57]|
```

Note that there are NULL values in the `jsonb` object. So at this point `ids` is going to be of type `jsonb` and what I need is to have an array of integers as I'm trying to query for:

```
SELECT int_array_ids @> '{33,34,35}' FROM my_table;
```

Once I'm able to have a converted `ids` to `INT[]` I can create indexes to speed my array contains queries.

I tried a subquery using `array_agg` but it's terrible slow:

```
SELECT array_agg(arrayed.am_id) FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(scrape->'amenity_ids') AS am_id
    FROM my_table
) AS arrayed
GROUP BY arrayed.id
```

Comment: try this : `SELECT COALESCE(translate(scrape->>'amenity_ids', '[]', '{}') :: int[], '{}'::int[]) AS ids FROM my_table`

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array
`SELECT d.am_id
FROM   my_table t, LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(scrape->'amenity_ids'))
   ) d(am_id);` try this.